# Is this an exact differential equation or a first order non-linear ordinary differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve this :
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\left(\frac{y^2}{x^3}-x\right)=\frac{y^3}{x^4}+y$$
using the exact  [equations](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Exact.aspx) method, but the final answer was getting very ugly with this form:

$$\frac{y^3}{3x^3}-xy=c$$

is there any other way that is simpler to solve this equation?
I checked this on  [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differential+equations+y%27*(y%5E2%2Fx%5E3-x)%3D(y%5E3)%2Fx%5E4%2By%20) and it gave me that it is a first order non-linear ordinary differential equation.

Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: It is a nonlinear first order ODE: the highest order derivative is of first order and it has terms with $y^2$ and $y^3$. However, it's also an exact ODE (as the very link you provided from WolframAlpha states). Your solution is a cubic equation on $y$, that seems to be solvable as an explicit solution for $y$, as WolframAlpha shows. If it's a homework assignment, I think that the solution you found is perfectly fine.